# bash expansion adding single quotes causing error

Tags: bash, cifs

I have a command to mount a `cifs` fileshare. The share path and mount point are added  with variables in the bash script like so;

`sudo mount -t cifs -o user="$USERNAME",cruid="$USERNAME",sec=krb5 "$FILEPATH" "$DFS_MOUNT"`

However, when the script is run the command fails? I can only assume that it's due to single quotes being added when I run the script with `bash -x` to check it?

It ends up looking like;

`sudo mount -t cifs -o user=chris,cruid=chris,sec=krb5 '//toolshed/Windows/Utilities/Uninstall\ Problems\ Fixit' /home/chris/fixit`

Which results in A failure saying path isn't found?

because if I run the command;
`sudo mount -t cifs -o user=chris,cruid=chris,sec=krb5 //toolshed/Windows/Utilities/Uninstall\ Problems\ Fixit /home/chris/fixit`

It works fine

Comment: *I can only assume that it's due to single quotes being added when I run the script with bash -x to check it?* Not too likely, such a problem would have shown up and be fixed a long time ago... what to you get with `echo "$FILEPATH"`? If you got the file name from `ls`, there are options of `ls` that make files with spaces be automatically bracketed.

Comment: `//toolshed/Windows/Utilities/Uninstall\ Problems\ Fixit`

Comment: So, you have a name that contains two characters, backslash+space and not an escaped space (`echo` doesn't escape spaces by itself). Your problem is upstream.

Comment: I thought the space was escaped by the backslash

Comment: This only true when you use a "string literal" to specify a string (without putting quotes) in a command line or in your source code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means. How do I fix it?

Comment: Don't use quotes and backslashes at the same time...

Comment: Is my answer invisible? Oh well... If it's not enough to solve the problem, can I have some feedback?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `$FILEPATH` expands to a string containing backslashes (`\`) that look as if they are meant to escape spaces that follow.

Double-quoted `$FILEPATH` is substituted by the variable value and does not undergo further word splitting. There's no need to escape spaces in its *content*. Even if unquoted, these backslashes would not escape spaces after variable expansion.

`bash -x` shows you the command with single-quotes added to make it less ambiguous. The single-quotes are for you, `mount` did not see them. Backslashes however were sent to `mount` because they are in the content of the variable. This way the tool requested a path that doesn't exist.

The right thing is to assign the literal string in the first place:

```
FILEPATH='//toolshed/Windows/Utilities/Uninstall Problems Fixit'
```

and then use the variable in double-quotes (as you did): `"$FILEPATH"`.

---

Note this would also work:

```
FILEPATH=//toolshed/Windows/Utilities/Uninstall\ Problems\ Fixit
```

but these backslashes now escape spaces at the moment the assignment is parsed, they do not survive to the variable content. Unquoted backslashes in the command that worked for you were parsed in the same way, they didn't get to `mount`.

Your problem was the backslashes were in the content of the variable. Maybe you did something like:

```
FILEPATH='//toolshed/Windows/Utilities/Uninstall\ Problems\ Fixit'  # wrong in your case
```

---

Please note [it is a good practice to use `lowercase` variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).

Comment: I understand the above, but I am trying to implement it